# With Oauth2 Google Extension for Geoserver, GeoServer home page does not redirect to Google Login page

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, geoserver, google-oauth

I have installed the OAuth2 Extensions for Geoserver successfully and I was able to create the Authentication Filter and added Google_Oauth2 to  the filter chains web
rest
gwc
default

I have also created the truststore and added it to the JAVA_OPTS Path as as ../cacerts.cks

All the steps I have followed are as in the official [docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/oauth2/index.html)

Now, when I navigate to the Geoserver Home Page as directed by the Docs, I'm not getting the Google Login Page as supposed to.

One of the issues I have discovered is after adding the Google-Oauth2 to the filter chains, when I logout as Geoserver admin, the Google-Oauth is again removed from the selected chains.

What I'd like to know is how to do a stepwise check to determine the root cause of this problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

I have the Google Login ICon, when I click on it I get a 404 Error for this URL http://:8080/geoserver/web/j_spring_oauth2_google_login

Here is the Logfile, I cant find anything in here to point to the problem, just a few warnings here and there which are not related to Authentication

```
04 Jul 15:08:00 DEBUG [geoserver.global] - Found Java environment variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR to be unset
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:00.911 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'XStreamPersisterInitializer', but ApplicationContext is unset.
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:00.912 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:00.914 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:00.914 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
    log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [geoserverlogfile].
    log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:03.435 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'GeoServerSecurityProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:03.435 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:03.435 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:03.435 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
    04 Jul 15:08:04 INFO [config.GeoServerPropertyConfigurer] - Loading properties file from org.geoserver.config.SpringResourceAdaptor@6653368c
    04 Jul 15:08:04 INFO [geoserver.monitor] - Configuring monitoring database from: monitoring/db.properties
    04 Jul 15:08:04 WARN [impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] - InitialContext did not implement EventContext
<Loaded smth........>
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache.xml' in directory '/var/lib/geoserver_data/gwc'.
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:07 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
    04 Jul 15:08:07 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** GWC configuration validation error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'gwcConfiguration'.
    04 Jul 15:08:07 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** Will try to use configuration anyway. Please check the order of declared elements against the schema.
    04 Jul 15:08:07 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base directory is: gwc-layers
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from gwc-layers
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [layer.TileLayerDispatcher] - Configuration gwc contained no layers.
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - **************************************************************************************************************************
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found Servlet context parameter GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to /var/lib/geoserver_data, using it as the default prefix. ***
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - **************************************************************************************************************************
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota.xml' in directory '/var/lib/geoserver_data/gwc'.
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota-jdbc.xml' in directory '/var/lib/geoserver_data/gwc'.
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - Quota config is: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
    04 Jul 15:08:07 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:09 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:09 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - Quota config is: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
    04 Jul 15:08:09 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
    04 Jul 15:08:09 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task
    04 Jul 15:08:09 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas.
    04 Jul 15:08:09 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 24 layers attached to global quota 500.0 MB
    04 Jul 15:08:09 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 30 SECONDS
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WPSInfoImpl--ecf5ed2:15cf44cc45b:-8000', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wcs', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl--387a6a83:15d0d802c5c:-8000', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wms', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wfs', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WPSInfoImpl-2db12f5c:15cf83a5f1b:-7fdb', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl-2db12f5c:15cf83a5f1b:-7fdc', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl-2db12f5c:15cf83a5f1b:-7fdf', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl-2db12f5c:15cf83a5f1b:-7fde', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl-2db12f5c:15cf83a5f1b:-7fdd', enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [geoserver.monitor] - Monitor hibernate extension enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:10 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wps] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wps/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/temp/**] onto handler 'filePublisher'
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 89 bindable processes in Deprecated processes
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 5 bindable processes in GeoServer specific processes
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 48 bindable processes in Geometry processes
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 30 bindable processes in Vector processes
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:ConvolveCoverage as the input kernel of type class javax.media.jai.KernelJAI cannot be handled
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input zones of type class java.lang.Object cannot be handled
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input nodata of type class it.geosolutions.jaiext.range.Range cannot be handled
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input rangeData of type class java.lang.Object cannot be handled
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the output zonal statistics of type interface java.util.List cannot be handled
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 17 bindable processes in Raster processes
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wcs] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wcs/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:11 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock is enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:11 WARN [turbojpeg.TurboJPEGMapResponse] - The turbo jpeg encoder is available for usage
    04 Jul 15:08:12 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:12 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:12 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml/icon/**/*] onto handler 'kmlIconService'
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/gwc/service/**] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing GeoRSS poller in a background job...
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run.
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [rest.RESTDispatcher] - Created RESTDispatcher with 15 paths
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wms] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:13 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wms/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:14 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/animate/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:14 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/animate] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:14 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/TestWfsPost] onto handler 'wfsTestServlet'
    04 Jul 15:08:14 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wfs/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:14 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wfs] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:17 INFO [geoserver.monitor] - Monitor extension enabled
    04 Jul 15:08:18 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/ows/**] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:18 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/ows] onto handler 'dispatcher'
    04 Jul 15:08:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
    04 Jul 15:08:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
    04 Jul 15:08:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3 concurrency level
    04 Jul 15:08:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:18.990 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to java.lang.String
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readTypeString(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
            at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:719)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:882)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1815)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doReadObject(StandardSession.java:1611)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1077)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:218)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:162)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:356)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5224)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.031 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver.war has finished in 27,515 ms
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.032 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.060 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 28 ms
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.061 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.079 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 18 ms
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.079 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 137 ms
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.227 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 10 ms
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.228 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.238 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 10 ms
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.245 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.254 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    04-Jul-2017 15:08:19.274 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 27815 ms
    04 Jul 15:08:19 WARN [util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
    04 Jul 15:08:19 ERROR [util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
      Detail: Failing row contains (null, FINISHED, OTHER, /, null, null, null, 0, 192.168.1.235, ROS-GS3, GET, 2017-07-04 15:08:19.893, 2017-07-04 15:08:19.911, 18, 192.168.1.185, null, null, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KH..., null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, 0, null, null, 200, null, 1, 1, -1, -1, null).
    04 Jul 15:08:19 WARN [util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
    04 Jul 15:08:19 ERROR [util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
      Detail: Failing row contains (null, FINISHED, OTHER, /, null, null, null, 0, 192.168.1.235, ROS-GS3, GET, 2017-07-04 15:08:19.893, 2017-07-04 15:08:19.911, 18, 192.168.1.185, null, null, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KH..., null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, 0, null, null, 200, null, 1, 1, -1, -1, null).
    04 Jul 15:26:15 WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 192.168.1.185
    04 Jul 15:26:15 INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 1672ms
    04 Jul 15:26:16 INFO [geoserver.security] - Strong cryptography is available
```

**I dug a little deeper and found this**

```
2017-07-04 14:52:19,339 WARN [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/geoserver/j_spring_oauth2_google_login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 1):

would it be possible for you to provide the piece of GeoServer logs concerning the authentication phase?

It should report any potential exception you might encounter. If not, try to rise up the GeoServer Log Level to DEBUG.

Usually that behavior means that somehow the request to the OAuth2 Provider fails, and in your specific case (if I understood correctly what you are trying to do) most probably it depends on PKIX issue with certs. It is possible that somehow you did not correctly configured the truststore on your Tomcat instance.

Also keep in mind that if you want to enable SSL protocol you also need to use HTTPS endpoint for your GeoServer instance. Otherwise I kindly suggest to go for the plain one.