# GeoServer OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, geoserver

Is anyone out there using OAuth to authenticate GeoServer users? I've been through installing and configuring this [extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/oauth2/index.html).  I've tried Google and GitHub providers.  I end up with a 404 error trying to access the login page.  Same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821277/with-oauth2-google-extension-for-geoserver-geoserver-home-page-does-not-redirec).  There are no errors in the log with the debug level elevated as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here...

For me the 404 problem solved by building from source and accounting for the required dependencies using a maven plugin.  Previously, I was attempting to use the prebuilt binaries and lib/ depedencies.

I built the modules from source (2.18.3) and modified the file maven file to copy the dependencies to the target folder, which I then copied to WEB-INF/lib.

Here is the pom file addition I made to get the dependencies.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
              <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```